# How to select a row based on a part of value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
// qanda
+----+---------+-----------------------+------------------------+
| id |  title  |        content        |          tags          |
+----+---------+-----------------------+------------------------+
| 1  | title1  | content1              | <a>tagA<a/><a>tagB</a> |
| 2  | title2  | content2              | <a>tagA</a><a>tagC</a> |
| 3  | title3  | content3              | <a>tagM</a><a>tagB</a> |
| 4  | title4  | content4              | <a>tagD</a>            |
| 5  | title5  | content5              | <a>tagA</a><a>tagG</a> |
+----+---------+-----------------------+------------------------+
```

And I want to select every row which has `tagB`. So this is expected result:

```
+----+---------+-----------------------+------------------------+
| 1  | title1  | content1              | <a>tagA<a/><a>tagB</a> |
| 3  | title3  | content3              | <a>tagM</a><a>tagB</a> |
+----+---------+-----------------------+------------------------+
```

How can I do that?

---

Currently I have created an *FULLTEXT* index on `tags` column and find it like this:

```
. . . WHERE MATCH ( tags ) AGAINST ( :tag )
```

But my approach has two problems:

1. Sometimes `tags` columns is containing something like this value: `<a class="tagA">tagB</a>`. In this case I want to select that row only for `tagB`, But it will be selected both for `tagA` and `tagB`.
2. I cannot select multiple tags. Ex: I cannot select rows which have either `tagA` or `tagB` or `tagC`.

Comment: Please don't tell me *"you shouldn't keep tags like this"*. Because SO keeps tags exactly as I do https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/421098

Comment: `SELECT * FROM qanda WHERE tags LIKE '%tagB%';`

Comment: To tweak @PaulL, `LIKE '%>tagB<%'`. The minute difference is it should solve your Problem #1.

Answer (score -1):

You can use reglar expression in your query :

[Regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm)

In MySQL you cna use like mentione din following section : 
[MYSQL regular expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)